# Reading a remote HTTPS URL in Domino LotusScript

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

When I used set doc=db.GetDocumentByURL(url,1,1,,,,,False) to get a page/file under http, it returned the web page/file successfully as a Notes document.

But when I used set doc=db.GetDocumentByURL(url,1,1,username,password,,,False) to get an **ssl page/file under https**, where url is like "https://docs.google.com/document/d/xxxxoooo/edit", it failed and the remote console showed the error messages:

**SSL Error: Keyring File access error**

**Connection interrupted: SSL Error: Bad or missing remote certificate**

Can't db.GetDocumentByURL() access an ssl page/file? What should I do?

Comment: Nevertheless db.GetDocumentByURL(url,1,1,username,password,,,False) failed to get the ssl page/file, it still returned a Notes document, which includes the Body item (Data Type:HTML) of value "<H1>ERROR</H1>The requested document (URL https://docs.google.com/document/d/xxxxoooo/edit) could not be accessed.<p>The remote server is not trusted." and the item HTTPStatus and status both have the same value of "503", and a item of PrivatePage of value "1".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows - make sure that IE can open the page. I've seen this problem in case the server's SSL certificate was self-signed and installing it in IE solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows, and my IE can open the page. But still the same error message on server console.

Comment: well, I meant using IE on server to open the url

Comment: In which context does this agent run? Client or server?